# Использовать только String в Java

Tags: java, строки

Почему цикл останавливается после первого слова? удалить буквы из каждого слова,которые такие же как первая!

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "  asfvassab dfdfa  ";
        String text = s.trim();
        System.out.println(text);

        if ( text.length() == 0 )
            System.out.println("The text is empty!");
        else {
            String result = "";
            String buffer = "";
            int a = 0; // маркер початку слова
            int b = text.indexOf(" "); // маркер кінця слова
            if (b == -1) // Виключна ситуація з рядком з одного слова
                b = text.length();

            while (b != -1) {
                char buf[] = new char [b-a];
                text.getChars(a, b, buf, 0) ;
                for (int i: buf) {
                    text = text.substring(a, b);
                    String searchChar = "" + text.charAt(0);
                    buffer = text.replaceAll(searchChar, "");
                }

                a = b;
                b = text.indexOf(" ", b);

                if (a == text.lastIndexOf(" "))
                    b = text.length();
            }
            System.out.println(b);
            result += buffer;
            System.out.print(result); // Вивід результату
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ты обрезаешь только первое слово пределами `a` и `b`. Поиск этих границ нужно зациклить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text = text.substring(a, b);//обрезает text до первого слова
b = text.indexOf(" ", b);//ищется следующий пробел, которого уже нет
```